# How does std::cout print negative zero in a ones-complement system?

Tags: c++

On a ones-complement platform, what would the following code print?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 1, j = -1;

    std::cout << i+j << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would suspect it would print "0" instead of "-0", but I can't seem to find anything authoritative.

**Edit:** To clarify, I am interested in how -0 would be printed, several people have suggested that in practice, the implementation of ones-compliment might not generate a negative zero with the above code.

In those cases, the following has been suggested to actually generate a -0:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << ~0 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The question still remains: what will this print?

Comment: Prints `0` on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac6c491f7ca7f7a9). And I'm pretty sure that's what supposed to happen every time.

Comment: I doubt this will ever print `-0` on any system.

Comment: Permission to tag this C too? I hypothecate that C programmers are closer to this stuff.

Comment: You also have to bear in mind the rules that IOStreams uses to render integers. I doubt it bothers with a special case for `-0` to be quite honest.

Comment: Presumably streams can apply the same rules as they do for negative floating point zero.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm sure coliru doesn't use a ones-complement CPU; negative zero is impossible in two's complement.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit does that mean it's implementation-defined then? I think this is a great question for the language lawyers out there.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yeah could be a good question - how well-specified is IOStream output for numbers?

Comment: @Bathsheba I was more curious on how iostream specifically handles the negative zero case, but if tagging it "C" broadens the question significantly to generate better answers, by all means go for it.

Comment: I made an update to the question in light of @Bathsheba's response. (And thanks to MarkRansom's suggestion to use the bitwise negation on zero to generate a negative zero. Feel free to edit if my update makes things *more* unclear instead of less.

Comment: Since C doesn't have `cout`, I'd leave the tag as is. `printf` might behave completely differently.

Comment: `operator<<` is specified in terms of `num_put`, which is specified in terms of `printf`, which is specified in terms of `fprintf`.  But I can't find any answer for what `fprintf` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, just to clarify thing, crafting a negative zero using bitwise operations and then using the resulting value is not portable. That said, nothing specifies in the documentation of `fprintf` (thus, of `std::basic_ostream::operator<<(int)`) whether the sign bit in the representation of int corresponds to a padding bit in the representation of `unsigned` or an actual value bit.

As a conclusion, this is unspecified behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << ~0 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using  bitwise operations to create an integer negative zero certainly *is* portable to other one's-complement computers. True, it won't work on a two's-complement computer, it won't work because negative zero doesn't exist in two's-complement.

Comment: "certainly is portable to other one's-complement computers:" that's what I'd call not portable ;).

Comment: @YSC This question only applies to ones-compliment computers, so for all intents and purposes here, I agree with George.

Comment: `~0` certainly is code that is valid and will compile/run fine on both platforms. I understand what it will print on a twos compliment machine (`-1`). I'm trying to understand what the behaviour is on a ones-compliment machine.

Comment: @George @Tyzoid Everybody agrees that `~0` construct is portable as long as you stay on two's-complement or one's complement architectures; let us not diverge and fuss about wording. If you're not comfortable with my first sentence, just focus on the second and third ones that bring the added-value of my intervention.

Comment: @Tyzoid That's fair. The glibc source is no authoritative *spec* though.

Comment: @YSC I agree that it's no authoritative spec, as it is an implementation. However, it's the closest to something authoritative that I could find.

Comment: Yeah! Bounty! I'll use it properly.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed adding `n` to `-n` *should* give you a negative zero. But the generation of -0 doesn't happen in practice since 1's complement addition uses a technique called a *complementing subtractor* (the second argument is complemented and subtracted from the first).

(The idiomatic way of getting a signed floating point zero doesn't apply here since you can't divide an integer by zero).

Comment: I don't know much about such things - but is it possible to get a negative zero by dividing -1 by some larger-magnitude positive number (using integer division)? (or indeed positive 1 by some larger-magnitude negative)

Comment: I'm very rusty too on this - I haven't messed about with 1's complement since my university days - but, as far as I recall, all arithmetic operations on 1's complement are implemented so you *don't* end up with a signed negative zero.

Comment: If you *know* you have a one's complement system, generating negative zero for testing is easy: `~0`. And while true it's difficult to get a negative zero naturally on such a system, I don't think it's impossible. This doesn't really answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 5):

Looking through the glibc source code, I found these lines in vfprintf.c:

```
532       is_negative = signed_number < 0;                    \
533       number.word = is_negative ? (- signed_number) : signed_number;      \
534                                           \
535       goto LABEL (number);                            \
...
683       if (is_negative)                            \
684         outchar (L_('-'));                            \
```

So it would appear that the condition is `signed_number < 0`, which would return false for a `-0`.

as @Ysc mentioned, nothing in the documentation gives any specification to printing `-0`, so a different implementation of libc (on a ones-compliment) platform may yield a different result.

Answer (score 0):

If we view the theoretical point of the one's complement. Since the zero is defined as (+/-)0 there will be two binary values for 0 if we have 4 Bit values the zero will be 0000 (+0) and 1111 (-0). As a result of this you always have to do a correction if an operation, addition or substraction, has a zero-crossing operation in it.

So for example if we do the following operation `-2+6=4` the result will be calculated as followed:

```
  1101 (-2)
+ 0110 (6)
------
 1100  (add carry)
======
  0011 (+3)
```

As you can see in the Bit operation the result is incorrect and is only the incomplete result. In this case we have to add a +1 to the value to get the correct result. To identify if the +1 has to be added we have to take a look at the add carry result. If the most left numer **1**100 is a ONE than we have to add +1 to the result to get the correct result.

If we have a look at your example:

```
  0001 (+1)
+ 1110 (-1)
------
 0000  (add carry)
======
  1111 (-0)
```

We see that the result will be -0 and this will be the final result because the left add carry bit is 0.

Comment: While correct, I am familiar with the mechanics of ones-compliment addition (in fact, this is why I cited `(-0) = (-1) + 1` in my original post). My question is what it will output in the C++ standard/an actual ones compliment machine.