# Why "int" variable doesn't print negative zero?

Tags: c++, types, floating-point, int

In the following program, `float` variable print negative zero.

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float val = 0;
    val = -val;

    std::cout<<val<<std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
-0
```

But, in following code

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int val = 0;
    val = -val;

    std::cout<<val<<std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

print positive zero.

Why `int` variable doesn't print negative zero?

Comment: Because there integer representation on your system doesn't have negative zeros? Who said there should be a negative zero?

Comment: ints don't have a negative zero in the usual representation, and they don't have as much use for one.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why not post an answer? Comments not being for answers and all that...

Comment: @juanchopanza - Is it an answer? I don't know the OP's platform to answer.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is clear, with example code and documented output. And it is not that obvious.

Comment: @n.m. I'm pretty sure the C++ standard allows integer representations with negative zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Answer (score 11):

There's no such thing as negative zero in the set of mathematical integers.

Some rarely used machine representations of integers do have more than one representation of zero, and in this case one of them may be customarily called a "negative zero". The C++ language however doesn't allow exposing such representation to the programmer through normal integer APIs. So even if your computer has such a representation, which it probably doesn't, it will not be printed as -0.

On the other hand, the most common representation of floating point numbers has signed zeros, and the C++ standard specifically allows for an implementation to expose the sign to the programmer.

Comment: This beautiful answer should have more upvotes. Have another.

Comment: Related: [How does std::cout print negative zero in a ones-complement system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33151068/5470596) And yes, have another.

Answer (score 4):

The *usual* way to handle negative integers in computers is by encoding them using [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). And using two's complement it's not possible to have a negative zero.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the C++ standard doesn't mandate two's complement, so there could be implementations out there with a negative zero integer.

Comment: Sign and magnitude representation in particular comes to mind, although I don't know of any real world, non-archaic platform which uses it for integers. In general, I would be hard pressed to find a non-2's complement signed integers implementation in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers with floating point consists of sign, exponent and fraction. If sign is `1`, its negative and if sign is `0`, its positive number.

As you can see on example below

[image]

---

While negative numbers in computer are usually handled by `twos complement` so if number has most significant bit `1`, you have to convert it from twos complement to get real value. For example on 8 bits.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

First step: Reverse bits

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Second step: Add 1

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Third step: Change sign

So result is `-128`.

In other words you cant have `-0` in twos complement.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the binary representations of int and float are different from each other.

An `int` consists of 32 bits, the most significant one being the sign bit. The highest possible value of int when the sign bit is true is `11111111111111111111111111111111`, which is -1. So negative zero isn't possible.

Signed floating point numbers, on the other hand, are divided up into three parts - sign, exponent, and mantissa (fraction). So, when the fraction part is equal to zero,  the whole number is equal to zero. When you toggle the sign bit (which is essentially what you did by `val = -val`), the number is technically still zero, but when you tell `cout` to convert that number to a string of decimal digits that you can read, it sees that the sign bit is set to 1 and just throws the minus sign at the beginning of it. i hope that makes sense